# Why will firebase CLI say deploy complete and not deploy a function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm using the firebase-tools CLI to deploy firebase functions. I'm trying to deploy a function using `firebase deploy --only functions:functionName`.

This is in an existing project. The functions are located in `/functions/index.js`.

Up until a few hours ago, deploying worked fine. But now when trying to deploy a new function I get the following:

```
i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

+  Deploy complete!
```

But it clearly does not even upload anything or deploy a function. Trying to deploy an existing function, I get `The following functions are found in your project but do not exist in your local source code:`

I'm a bit baffled as to how this seems to have "broken". Even looking at the git for the project there have been no changes to any config files or anything, other than writing a new function. I have not updated any packages since last deploying, and have tried the previous version of `firebase-tools` as well as the latest version.

Deploying a different function to a different project in the same manner is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I had created a file called functions.js in the project root directory (not /functions directory) and it appears `firebase-tools` was looking to that (empty) file for its functions, instead of the functions directory. Strange, and no kind of error message since I guess the file it thought it was looking for did exist.

Comment: Ran into the same infuriating problem. Thanks so much for posting this!

Answer (score 0):

In my case , index.js was not updated properly . Make sure index.js file exports the function like below :

`const functions = require('firebase-functions'); exports.functionName = functions.region('us-central1').onRun(handler);//or any  onRequest function`